# GST issue for Australian online purchase application using paypal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I'm in the process of setting up an online video application to sell Australian videos and others,  but i am getting stuck on the issues of GST (Australian Goods & Services Tax). From what i know, only residents of Australia must pay GST. How would i get PayPal to test if the purchaser is an Australian resident and includes 10% or if they are from outside Australia and don't pay any extra? Are there any resolved this? Also what happens when other countries have different taxes and tax rates for example New Zealand with a 12.5% gst?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you base it on the billing address? _"Also what happens when other countries have different taxes"_ - If you have an Australian site it's not really up to you to worry about what taxes may or may not apply in New Zealand or other countries, that's up to those countries' customs services to manage (the same way Australia does for goods coming in - you have to pay GST and possibly other duties on goods worth more than $1000).

Answer (score 0):

It is likely easier to use a third party to handle the monetary transactions, such as http://www.paypal.com/ but if this doesn't work for you, you may consider a GeoIP solution, or a "I am an Australian resident" checkbox. You could consider only marketing to Australians.